# get WP-API by page id

Tags: api, json

Im trying to get the json of my homepage, before i only got the json by post id and im not being able to get it by page. This is what im trying:

```
mysite.me/wp/v2/pages/2304
```

But it just redirects me to my homepage.
By post id, this is how i do it:

```
http://mysite.me/wp-json/mysite/v1/items/id/92570
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use v2 of the API (which is the current one you should be using), the endpoint is `mysite.me/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/1234` where 1234 is the page ID.

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/#retrieve-a-page

Comment: Hi there! That works great but do you know how to retrieve multiple posts by their id at once?

Comment: @user3191334 you can use the [`include` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/#arguments). For example, `mysite.me/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?include[]=1&include[]=2` would get you pages with the ID 1 and 2.